# Detect wake from hibernation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to detect a wake from hibernation? I am developing an extension that displays information when the user turns on the computer and logs in to the system. I can do that easily by setting the extension to run when the system starts and execute the codes instantly.

background.js

```
function displayInfo(){ /*...*/ }

displayInfo();
```

However, some users might not turn off their computer, rather, they would hibernate for faster wake time. Hibernate should still be considered that the user is "turning on" the computer, but currently I have no way of detecting that.

Is there anyway I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

No "perfect/foolproof" method, but some  an idea:

- Record the system time every 5 minutes or so.  If the current time is much larger than the expected time, assume it slept/hibernated.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but one problem I notice is that if the timer interval is set too high, it will take too long for it to realize the computer is waken from hibernation.